# modifying qformat: add the points at the end of the question in line with it

Tags: exam

I'd like to modify the qformat so that the points of the questions appear in line with and at the end, but not in the right margin.

Like in this word example.

[image]

I've tried modifying qformat, but it looks like it's made to always start the question on a new line, like in this MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{exam}

\qformat{\thequestion. \hfill (\thepoints)}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question i will give you no points
\begin{parts}
    \part[3] This is a part 
    \part[3] This is another part 
    \part[3] This is A part 
\end{parts}

\question[5] This question will give you some points

\noqformat
\question[1] Are you happy this is over?

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using the `\titledquestion` command (section 4.5.1, page 33). I included a top-aligned `\parbox` to limit the width of the question text, which offsets the point value. To me, that makes the point value easier for you and your students to see. You can adjust the width of the `\parbox` as needed.

I also created a second `\qformat` option that puts the points one the same line as the end of the question. This more closely resembles your example but I do not think it looks as good as the above option. In addition, my macro can sometimes lead to the point value being placed on the left side of the page if the question takes a full line. Unfortunately, I do not know how to correct this.

The `\renewcommand` macro is necessary only if you are using a combination of `\qformat` and `\noqformat` questions because the question numbers did not align properly without it.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{exam}

\renewcommand{\questionshook}{%
  \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelsep}%
}

% Places points on first line of question. You can adjust text width to suit your needs.
\qformat{\thequestion. \parbox[t]{0.8\textwidth}{\thequestiontitle}\hfill(\thepoints)}

% Use this if you want the points to occur on the last line of the question. 
% Caveat: If your question occupies a full line, the points will appear on the left side
% of the new line. Plus, I don't think it looks as good.
%\qformat{\thequestion. \parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\thequestiontitle\hfill(\thepoints)}\hfill}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\titledquestion{i will give you no points}[0]
\begin{parts}
    \part[3] This is a part 
    \part[3] This is another part 
    \part[3] This is A part 
\end{parts}

\titledquestion{This question will give you some points}[5]

\titledquestion{This question works fine for the second \qformat. text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text}[5]

\titledquestion{This question puts the points at the left side fo the page. text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text }[5]

\noqformat
\question[1] Are you happy this is over?

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Here's the results of the first `\qformat`.

[image]

Here's the results of the second `\qformat` that shows the problem if the question occupies ends with a full line. If you prefer this format, then careful rewording of a problematic question to shorten or lengthen it would put the points where you need.

[image]

Comment: Can you try using the normal `\question` with this code, because this works with `\titledquestion{}` but when I try to use normal `\question`s in the same document something weird happens.

Comment: @piptin I tried for a long time to figure out how to make this work with `\question` but was not successful. I do not know Tex well enough to understand the complete inner workings of the exam class. However, what you wanted works very well with `\titledquestion.` You'd have to use `\titledquestion` question through or use `\noqformat` before the places you use `\question`, as I did for Question 4 in the example output. Sorry, but I do not know of another solution.